# JQuery ui error with custom css

Tags: jquery

I am trying to render a file's code for Jquery and its giving me a type error. I am not able to figure it out what kind of error it is referring to.

My error is :
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined

My file and line it is showing the error in browser debug  mode is:

```
function(a)
{returnd._keydown(a)}.next().attr("role","tabpanel");

d.headers.not(d.active||"").attr({"aria-
expanded":"false",tabIndex:-1}).next().hide();

d.active.length?d.active.attr({"aria-expanded":
"true",tabIndex:0}):d.headers.eq(0).attr("tabIndex",0);

b.browser.safari||d.headers.find("a").attr("tabIndex",-1);

e.event&&d.headers.bind(e.event.split(" ").join(".accordion ")
+".accordion",function(a){d._clickHandler.call(d,a,this);

a.preventDefault()})},_createIcons:function(){var d=this.options;
```

Comment: It's telling you that b.browser is not set to anything. Without more code, that's all we can tell you.

Comment: Please don't post minified code like this. Use meaningful variable names so we can understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

b.browser isn't being found, probably because it was removed in jQuery 1.9, so try 1.8 instead:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```